# How to create full text search query in mongodb with spring-data?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have spring-data-mogodb application on java or kotlin, and need create text search request to mongodb by spring template.

In mongo shell it look like that:

```
  db.stores.find(
   { $text: { $search: "java coffee shop" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
  ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

I already tried to do something but it is not exactly what i need:

```
@override fun getSearchedFiles(searchQuery: String, pageNumber: Long, pageSize: Long, direction: Sort.Direction, sortColumn: String): MutableList<SystemFile> {

    val matching = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching(searchQuery)


    val match = MatchOperation(matching)
    val sort = SortOperation(Sort(direction, sortColumn))
    val skip = SkipOperation((pageNumber * pageSize))
    val limit = LimitOperation(pageSize)

    val aggregation = Aggregation
            .newAggregation(match, skip, limit)
            .withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build())

    val mappedResults = template.aggregate(aggregation, "files", SystemFile::class.java).mappedResults


    return mappedResults
}
```

May be someone already working with text searching on mongodb with java, please share your knowledge with us )

Comment: Can you tell exactly what you need? I can give you an example of my own using `MongoRepository`, `MongoTemplate` and optionally an `Aggregation` but I'd like to be sure that what you're looking for.

Comment: @charlycou i need to create an query with  "Text Search" https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/
and sorting
and this request should return to me collection of my object, not mongo Document

Answer (score 11):

### Setup Text indexes

First you need to set up text indexes on the fields on which you want to perform your text query.

If you are using Spring data mongo to insert your documents in your database, you can use `@TextIndexed` annotation and indexes will be built while inserting your document.

```
@Document
class MyObject{
  @TextIndexed(weight=3) String title;
  @TextIndexed String description;
}
```

If your document are already inserted in your database, you need to build your text indexes manually

```
TextIndexDefinition textIndex = new TextIndexDefinitionBuilder()
  .onField("title", 3)
  .onField("description")
  .build();
```

After [the build and config of your mongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template) you can pass your text indexes/

```
template.indexOps(MyObject.class).ensureIndex(textIndex);
```

### Building your text query

```
List<MyObject> getSearchedFiles(String textQuery){
  TextQuery textQuery = TextQuery.queryText(new TextCriteria().matchingAny(textQuery)).sortByScore();
  List<MyObject> result = mongoTemplate.find(textQuery, MyObject.class, "myCollection");
  return result
}
```